# Cannot connect access points with same name using Windows 10

Tags: android, wireless-access-point, ssid

Consider:

- a laptop running Windows 10
- a Samsung tablet running Android and having 4G internet access
- a Samsung phone running Android and having 4G internet access

The tablet and the phone should be usable alternatively to provide internet access to the computer through Wi-Fi.

The phone and the tablet use the same SSID, named "Android AP" and it seems impossible to edit it.

The computer can reach the Internet through the tablet but not to through the phone, altough they seem configured the same way. I assume that the computer remembers "Android AP" as the tablet access point, even when the tablet is off.

Deleting existing "Wireless network connection" in order to reset does not suffice.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the wireless SSID on either Samsung device with ease. Go to settings>connections>mobile hotspot and tethering> "click the slider to on". When you see "on" appear in blue, touch it. You will then be in the Mobile Hotspot section and you can click on the SSID "Android AP" and change it to anything you want. You also have the option to change the password.